# How can I make recursive query in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, recursion

I have tow tables like

users

```
id | name
_______________
1  | one
2  | two
3  | three
4  | four
5  | five
6  | six
```

employees

```
id | userId | reportedTo
_________________________
1  | 1      |   null
2  | 2      |   1
3  | 3      |   2
4  | 4      |   3
5  | 5      |   4
6  | 6      |   5
```

I need something like

if I run query for some user then it will return all the record which reportedTo is this user and other users which reportedTo is reportedTo this user

Like:

if I run this query for user 1 then it will return all the record accept userId 1 from employees

```
id | userId | reportedTo
    _________________________
    2  | 2      |   1
    3  | 3      |   2
    4  | 4      |   3
    5  | 5      |   4
    6  | 6      |   5
```

if I run query for userId 4 then it will return recornds with userId 5 and 6 from employee table

```
id | userId | reportedTo
    _________________________
    5  | 5      |   4
    6  | 6      |   5
```

can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you say 'recursive,' not 'recurring.' Recurring means it happens repeatedly, like with some time in between. Some readers will think you mean you want to use the [MySQL event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte(i, u, r) as (
   select * from employees where reportedTo = 1
   union all
   select e.* from cte c join employees e on c.u = e.reportedTo
)
select c.i id, c.u userId, c.r reportedTo from cte c;
```

Output:

| id | userId | reportedTo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 6 | 5 |

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=481e6103d5434b121210e0f0bcf8517d)